# How to put a string after the SQL IN

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

```
console.log("idList: ",idList);
```

My idList is a string with some numbers like `(1,3,5,7,9)`

How can I do something like this?

```
db.all('SELECT * FROM photoTags WHERE idNum IN idList',dataCallback);
```

If I directly use `(1,3,5,7,9)` instead of the `idList` variable, it works. But I could use `idList` in the SQL even I typed it as `"'+idList+'"` which return an empty string.

Comment: Which sql library are you using?

Comment: Why are there quotes at the end here `"'+idList+'"`?

Comment: Just concat the query with the string idList

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6 feature string interpolation

```
db.all(`SELECT * FROM photoTags WHERE idNum IN (${idList.toString()})`,dataCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code below splits @idNum variable value, then after, compares those splited values with table 'photTags' idNum. If input parameter @idNum value is in string and the table idNum value is in integer. No result will be displayed. Below code helps for such case :) :

```
DECLARE @idNum VARCHAR(100) = '1,3,5,7,9';
SELECT  *
  FROM photoTags 
  WHERE idNum IN  ( SELECT  value
   FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@idNum, ',') ); /*STRING_SPLIT Function 
                                             available only in 
                                             MS-SQL 2016*/
```

Comment: Realized what you said.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in the most ORMs to bind a list of values in a simple way.

Moreover if `idList` is a string and not an array, probably, you cannot use 
a prepared statement in this case.

Try straight forward concatenation (and don't forget the parenthesis around)

```
db.all('SELECT * FROM photoTags WHERE idNum IN ' +  idList, dataCallback);
```